# Is there a way to access files and information on an offline Linux server

Tags: centos, cpanel

We have a Linux server that was set up with CentOS and cPanel/WHM. It was taken out of service a few years ago but has some files and site information on it that were lost from our current server, and we would like to try and retrieve them from the old one. The machine is a Dell R530 that is just sitting in a closet right now with a display and keyboard connected. Assuming it will boot without an issue, here are my questions:

1. Without killing the machine, is there a way to go about finding and copying the files to an external USB drive, either directly or through another machine, using command line? I know the file hierarchy well enough to locate what we need if I can get in.
2. Can the machine be connected to a router so that I can access WHM using a browser on another machine on the local network?

Our office machines are all Mac OS, but I can bring in Windows or Linux machines if it makes for a better solution.

Apologies if this sounds like a hare-brained scheme. As should be apparent, I'm definitely not a server technician.

Comment: 1. Yes in any case (assuming it boots) you just need to plug your external drive and mount some of its fs. 2/ This might need extra (re)configuration and possibly software updates.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to just remove the disk drive and connect it to your current server.

If you don't want to do that you'll have to boot the machine and log in. If you don't have a valid login you can boot from an installation CD.

Once you're logged in there are several ways to get the files onto the new server:

- if the old machine has a network card you can use `rsync` to transfer the files
- if it has a USB port you can copy the files to a USB drive

Comment: "It might be easiest to just remove the disk drive and connect it to your current server" – Or not. There may be a RAID controller, so possibly we're dealing with multiple disks and the OP would have to recreate the proper config while being careful not to lose data in the process. Are you sure I'm wrong and there is no risk? Because if there is a risk then advising this to a person who is "definitely not a server technician" is not a good thing, unless you explain a safe procedure very well. "Just remove and connect" may be too vague.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The important word here is "might". Obviously if there's a RAID then it's going to be easier to boot the server.